# Regex to match specific words after one word

Tags: php, regex

So I have the following sample:

> Lorem ipsum dolor SEARCHWORD sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
>       Fusce lacus nisl, feugiat laoreet dignissim sit amet,
>       KEYWORD gravida vel velit. Nunc SEARCHWORD elementum risus orci, ac
>       tristique sem fringilla SEARCHWORD eget. Morbi maximus lectus nulla,
>       sed tempor nibh SEARCHWORD condimentum ut. Sed tincidunt cursus nibh

I want to match **all** the `SEARCHWORD` **after** the `KEYWORD` and replace them with surrounding Tags like `<b>SEARCHWORD</b>`. Have been trying and searching for one Day now... Is that even possible with regular expressions? If yes, does anybody have an idea how to solve this with a regex?

So, I am looking to match all SEARCHWORDs after the first occurrence of KEYWORD in the string. The expected output is:

> Lorem ipsum dolor SEARCHWORD sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
>       Fusce lacus nisl, feugiat laoreet dignissim sit amet,
>       KEYWORD gravida vel velit. Nunc **SEARCHWORD** elementum risus orci, ac
>       tristique sem fringilla **SEARCHWORD** eget. Morbi maximus lectus nulla,
>       sed tempor nibh **SEARCHWORD** condimentum ut. Sed tincidunt cursus nibh

I have tried this:

```
mb_ereg_replace('(?<=keyword)(.*?)(searchword)', '\1<b>\2</b>', $text, 'img');
```

Comment: What are you programming in? Show us your code.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `ereg_replace` is deprecated, but not `mb_ereg_replace`. unfortunately `preg_replace('/(?<=keyword)(.*?)(searchword)/iu', '\1<b>\2</b>', $test);` still does not work.

Comment: Yes, just double-checked. Try [**this demo**](https://regex101.com/r/aJ2uM0/3). I still do not know what your expected output is, so I do not understand what does not work, you should explain that in the question body, not in the comments.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew and i'm trying everything at https://regex101.com/, that's why the programing language is irrelevant if the regex works.

Comment: @mansur: regex101 has bugs and 3 options for only 3 regex flavors, and there are many more flavors. It is **very important** to know the regex flavor. Python `re` does not support `\G`, neither does Java.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew YES! Thanks! That is the regex I was searching for!

Comment: So, you were looking to match all `SEARCHWORD`s after the first occurrence of `KEYWORD` in the string. Please update the question with this requirement and add the expected output.

Comment: I don't think that this is possible, just because of the dynamic manner, but I will see the solution if there is one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To match all `SEARCHWORD`s after the first occurrence of `KEYWORD` in the string, you can use a `\G` based regex like

```
(?:KEYWORD|(?!^)\G).*?\KSEARCHWORD
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aJ2uM0/4)

The `(?:KEYWORD|(?!^)\G)` matches the first `KEYWORD` and then `(?!^)\G` requires the next match to appear right at the location of the previous match.

The `.*?` matches 0+ any characters (since the regex is to be used with DOTALL `/s` option) as few as possible up to the first `SEARCHWORD`, and `\K` omits the whole match value up to the search word.

[PHP demo](https://ideone.com/xiDwzF):

```
$re = '~(?:KEYWORD|(?!^)\G).*?\KSEARCHWORD~su'; 
$str = "Lorem ipsum dolor SEARCHWORD sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce lacus nisl, feugiat laoreet dignissim sit amet, KEYWORD gravida vel velit. Nunc SEARCHWORD elementum risus orci, ac tristique sem fringilla SEARCHWORD eget. Morbi maximus lectus nulla, sed tempor nibh SEARCHWORD condimentum ut. Sed tincidunt cursus nibh"; 
$result = preg_replace($re, "<b>SEARCHWORD</b>", $str);
echo $result;
```

**NOTE**: If you need to search for `SEARCHWORD`s  as whole words, enclose it with `\b`s (if the search word consists of alphanumeric / `_` characters), or with `(?<!\w)` and `(?!\w)` if the leading/trailing characters may be non-word characters.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to pass 'img' as options. See [this reference page](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.mb-ereg-replace.php).

```
    var_dump(mb_ereg_replace('.*?(keyword).*?(searchword).*?$', '\1<b>\2</b>', 'AAAAAAAAkeywordBBBBBBBCCCCCCsearchwordDDDDDD'));
   //output : string 'keyword<b>searchword</b>' (length=24)
```