# Count occurrences of specific word after a different, specific word is found

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, counting

I am rather new to regex and am stuck on the following where I try to use `preg_match_all` to [count the number of *hello* after *world*](https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/Cv6#tab-preg-match-all).

If I use `"world".+(hello)`, it counts to the in the last *hello*; `"world".*?(hello)` stops in the first *hello*, both giving one count.

```
blah blah blah
hello
blah blah blah
class="world" 
blah blah blah
hello 
blah blah
hello
blah blah blah
hello
blah blah blah
```

I am expecting `3` as the count because the `hello` before `world` should not be counted.

Comment: Wiktor demonstrated the required pattern over 5 years ago @ [Regex to match specific words after one word](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35792048/2943403).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single `preg_match_all` call here:

```php
$text = "blah blah blah\nhello\nblah blah blah\nclass=\"world\" \nblah blah blah\nhello \nblah blah\nhello\nblah blah blah\nhello\nblah blah blah";
echo preg_match_all('~(?:\G(?!^)|\bworld\b).*?\K\bhello\b~s', $text);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HNAA3S/1) and the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/7lAGr). *Details*:

- `(?:\G(?!^)|\bworld\b)` - end of the previous match (`\G(?!^)` does this check: [`\G` matches either start of the string or end of the previous match position](https://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html), so we need to exclude the start of string position, and this is done with the `(?!^)` negative lookahead) or a whole word `world`
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars, as few as possible
- `\K` - discards all text matched so far
- `\bhello\b` - a whole word `hello`.

**NOTE**: If you do not need word boundary check, you may remove `\b` from the pattern.

If `hello` and `world` are user-defined patterns, you must `preg_quote` them in the pattern:

```php
$start = "world";
$find = "hello";
$text = "blah blah blah\nhello\nblah blah blah\nclass=\"world\" \nblah blah blah\nhello \nblah blah\nhello\nblah blah blah\nhello\nblah blah blah";
echo preg_match_all('~(?:\G(?!^)|' . preg_quote($start, '~') . '\b).*?\K' . preg_quote($find, '~') . '~s', $text);
```

Comment: it works as intended, but just personally I have difficulty understanding it. what does (?!^) do ? I see excluding it will include matches before *world*.

Comment: @deanstreet I added this explanation to the answer. Also, see [Continuing at The End of The Previous Match](https://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html). Also, if you want to learn more about `\G` see [my YT video about `\G` use cases](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dsGUbvW5hsE&list=PL0l350Bvl3lI_KqlEAErGKBETpPtSsS9r&index=8).

Comment: I don't think you need `\K` here ;)

Comment: @bobblebubble That is of least importance, not necessary, but later, it might turn out a life savior :)

Comment: Something looks familiar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35792544/2943403

Comment: @mickmackusa Right, that is about replacing words after another word. There is also another problem related to the use of Unicode strings with `preg*` functions.

Answer (score 2):

Another option with simple regexes:

```
if(preg_match('/"world".*/s', $str, $out)) {
  echo preg_match_all('/\bhello\b/', $out[0]);
}
```

[See demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxj7AI4CLS6W4pEjBVkE9KScxQwFOcGWk5uTkc6EJJuckFhfbKpXnF@WkKClwYdOCJIrdDGyC6tZcXJlpGgVFqenxuYklyRka6vpQW/S09IvVdRRArgSS@aUlmpoK1VwKCqnJGfkKCA3xiTk5QE0xSWDjY5L01SGqow1iNa25av//BwA)

Comment: Isn't this doing the same thing as that suggested by @Tim Biegeleisen ? grabbing whatever after *world* and then counting *hello* whole words?

Comment: @deanstreet this one does 1.) match `"world"`... and anything after it 2.) if there is a match, it counts in the output all `hello`s. It is mandatory, that `"world"` exists in the string and the `hello`s occure after `"world"` to be counted in this one.

Comment: As a newbie, this divide-and-conquer is definitely easier to digest than the oneline regex suggested above, but that oneline works great.

Answer (score 1):

Other way: force the pattern to fail and to not retry if `world` doesn't exist in the string:

```
~(?:\A(*COMMIT).*?world)?.*?hello~s
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/7egSul/1)

The non-capturing group is optional but greedy. Consequence, it is tested each time the pattern is tried.
It begins with the `\A` anchor that matches the start of the string, so this is the only position where this group can succeed. After the start of the string, at other positions `\A` fails and since the group is optional, the remaining subpattern in it is ignored and the research continues with `.*?hello`.
Immediately after, there's the backtracking control verb `(*COMMIT)` that in case of failure after it, forces the pattern to not be retried at all. (end of the story).

In other words, if this group fails at the start of the string, the research is aborted once and for all.

Advantage: it needs less steps than a `\G` based pattern.

---

To be more efficient, a `\G` based pattern can also be written this way (using an optional group instead of an alternation):

```
~(?:\A.*?world)?(?!\A).*?hello~sA
```

Here the A modifier takes the role of the `\G` anchor, but it's exactly the same than starting each branch of a pattern (only one here) with the `\G` anchor.

Answer (score 0):

One approach might be to first strip off the leading portion of the string up to, and including, the first occurrence of `world`.  Then call `preg_match_all` as you already are doing and get the count of occurrences of `hello`.

```php
$input = "blah blah blah
hello
blah blah blah
class=\"world\" 
blah blah blah
hello 
blah blah
hello
blah blah blah
hello
blah blah blah";

$input = preg_replace("/^.*?\bworld/", "", $input);
preg_match_all("/\bhello\b/", $input, $matches);
echo sizeof($matches[0]);  // 4
```

Comment: This answer is flawed because it will fail if the trigger word (`world`) does not exist in the string.  The output is still `4` even if `world` is missing. Proof: https://3v4l.org/58vXC